# Is there a connection between the left null space and the annihilator of a matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, dual-spaces

The left null space of a matrix is a subspace. If it's OK to keep it real, the left subspace, $\mathcal L,$ of an $m \times n$ matrix, $M$, is a subspace of $\mathbb R^m.$ In my (limited) understanding, it can be thought of as the (sub)-space orthogonal to the column space, so that the dot product of the vectors in the left null space with the column vectors in $M$ is zero.

On the other hand, the Wikipedia definition of [annihilator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_space#Quotient_spaces_and_annihilators) as it refers to a subset is a follows:

> Let $S$ be a subset of $V$. The annihilator of $S$ in $V^*$, denoted here $S^o$, is the collection of linear functionals $f\in V^*$ such that $[f,s]=0$ for all $s\in S.$

Linear functionals in $V^*$ can be thought of as row vectors dotted with a elements in a vector space. In this sense, the parallelism with the left null space seems warranted.

So the question is:

Can the annihilator be compared in some way to the left null space?

Comment: What do you mean by "the parallelism with the left null space seems warranted"?  What do you mean by "parallelism"?

Comment: @littleO I am using "parallelism" as a lay term: it doesn't have any geometrical connotations. At my level of linear algebra, I look at functionals as simply dot products between a row vector and a vector in $V$, such that the result is zero. In the case of the annihilator (which I'm trying to understand), this seems very similar to my intuition of the left null: dotting a row vector with the column vectors in the matrix, the result is zero because they are orthogonal subspaces.

Comment: In the setting of $\mathbb R^n$, every linear functional can be "identified" with a vector, and the annihilator of a subspace can be "identified" with the orthogonal complement of the subspace.  We already know from the "four subspaces theorem" emphasized by Strang that the orthogonal complement of $R(M)$ is $N(M^T)$.  But the orthogonal complement of $R(M)$ "is" the annihilator of $R(M)$.  So, the four subspaces theorem can be rephrased in terms of annihilators rather than orthogonal complements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you think of the left null space of $M$ as consisting of row vectors, and you also think of the elements of the annihilator of a subspace as being row vectors, then **the left null space of $M$ is the annihilator of the range of $M$**.

Here is a proof. Let $z$ be a column vector in $\mathbb R^m$. Then
\begin{align}
z^T \in R(M)^\circ &\iff z^T Mx = 0 \quad \text{for all } x \in \mathbb R^n\\
&\iff (M^T z)^T x  = 0 \quad \text{for all } x \in \mathbb R^n\\
&\iff M^T z = 0 \\
&\iff z^T \text{ is in the left null space of $M$.}
\end{align}

---

Here is a generalization of the above fact.

Let $V$ and $W$ be finite dimensional vector spaces over a field $F$, and let $T:V \to W$ be a linear transformation.  Let $V^*$ and $W^*$ be the dual spaces of $V$ and $W$ (respectively) and let $T^*:W^* \to V^*$ be the dual of $T$, defined by
$$
\langle T^*z, x \rangle = \langle z, Tx \rangle.
$$
Then the annihilator of the range of $T$ is the null space of $T^*$:
$$
R(T)^\circ = N(T^*).
$$
This is a generalization of the "four subspaces theorem" emphasized in Gilbert Strang's linear algebra books. (This theorem is sometimes called the "fundamental theorem of linear algebra".)

Here's a proof:
\begin{align}
z \in R(T)^\circ &\iff \langle z, Tx \rangle = 0 \quad \text{for all } x \in V\\
&\iff \langle T^* z, x \rangle = 0 \quad \text{for all } x \in V \\
&\iff T^*z = 0 \\
&\iff z \in N(T^*).
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Hopefully it will help a lot of people, because it is clearly informed. For whatever it is worth, though, it went over my head in a big way... I'm very familiar with the four subspaces in Professor Strang's book, where he explains them in an extremely accessible way; yet, there is a chasm between the that level of linear algebra and your answer. It could be unavoidable, in which case, just disregard my comment.

Comment: @AntoniParellada I took a stab at writing an answer with perhaps more familiar notation.

Comment: @littleO $<T^* z, x> = <z, Tx>$ is technically the definition of the adjoint map, and not the definition of the dual map, no?

Comment: @mutantucle Let $W$ be a finite dimensional vector space over a field $F$, and let $w \in W$ and $z \in W^*$. I am using the notation $\langle z, w \rangle$ to denote $z(w)$. With this definition of $\langle z, w\rangle$ now made explicit, I believe my definition of $T^*$ is the standard dual map definition.

Comment: By the way, Lax’s great book Linear Algebra and its Applications has a good discussion of this topic, in chapter 2 I believe.

Comment: @littleO I see, thanks, all clear now!